# Office.js Excel Range getRow gives wrong range address

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js

In my Excel tab pane addin I want to get some rows from range based only on active selected rows.

Initially my data located in "Sheet1!H5:I16", and I select in worksheet only rows without tables f.e. "Sheet1!8:10"

For detect selected rows I get selected range and load some options:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    selectedRange.load(['address', 'rowIndex', 'rowCount']);
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            console.log(selectedRange.address);
    });
});
```

It gives me address "Sheet1!8:10" and selectedRange.rowIndex=7 and selectedRange.rowCount=3

Now I subtract my range row from selection:

```
var subsIndex = selectedRange.rowIndex - 5 // 5 is start index H5
```

And here I have my row inside data range rowIndex, it is 3.

Again: for whole worksheet my rowIndex is 7, for selection, intersected my data range, row index is 3.

Now I want to get first row of inside data range rowIndex(it must be Sheet1!H8:I10) from whole data Sheet1!H5:I16 based only on selected rows(selectedRange.rowIndex=7 and selectedRange.rowCount=3):

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var rangeAddress = "H5:I16"; // my whole data range
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress).getRow(subsIndex ); //try to get row number 3
    range.load('address');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(range.address); // gives me Sheet1!H5:I16 ??? 
    });
});
```

**Why getRange(3) gives me just whole range address Sheet1!H5:I16 insted address of row by index 3: Sheet1!H8:I8 ?**

[image]

Orange: data range

Red: Needed row

Comment: I tried your sample, but the output is Sheet1!H8:I8, which is exactly what I would have expected?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely followed your scenario.  But I think something like the following will work (and in fact, doesn't require you to load row indexes, etc.):

```
return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var selection = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    selection.format.fill.color = "purple";
    var range = selection.getRow(3);
    range.format.fill.color = "yellow"; 
    range.load('address');
    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log(range.address);
        })
        .then(ctx.sync);
}).catch(console.log);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, but getSelectedRange() will not be work for me in some cases. Sometimes users for update operations select whole rows instead range or users can select only one cell, but for operations with rows I need an Id column and to ensure that the Id column in selection(or for autodetection) I should take whole row. Working using row indexes is very useful for my cases and very frustrate that the getRow() not working as expected.

Comment: @AlexK, for getting whole row:  you can always call `range.getEntireRow()`.  Working with indexes is somewhat of an unsafe thing to do, because if the user or a co-author or the program itself adds rows above, the math will be off.

Comment: That being said:  I am still not convinced that getRow is doing the wrong thing.  Any chance you could create a simpler example, like the one I have above, but using indexes?